# Dynamic css font-size on a html div

Tags: html, css

I have a text in an html div and this div I can resize. I wanted the font size of the div to shrink as I resize it. Could I do this using only css?

I've tried using VW css but this is page related and not what I would like.

```
font-size: 3.5vw;
```

Comment: So you can use `calc()` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/ check this out i think it will help you.